# Chat user list sorted by activity, not name

Tags: bug, chat

On the user list at https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users, https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=online&sort=recent, etc., the description at the top reads:

> users who are online, sorted by name

However, the users actually appear to be sorted by most recent activity time, not name. The description should be corrected.

Incidentally, and maybe more "importantly", there doesn't currently seem to be a way to sort chat users by name.

Comment: I came here just now to report this same bug, and found this when typing up a bug report. How about that.

Comment: Join the club - happened to me more than once, one time I even posted own-duplicate.